# Probability that every ball picked was played exactly once

Tags: probability

A box contains 6 tennis balls. Peter picks two balls at random from the box, plays with them, and returns them to the box. Paul then picks two more balls at random from the box (they can be the same or different from Peter's balls), plays with them, and returns them to the box. Finally, Mary picks two more balls at random and plays with them. What is the probability that every ball picked was played with exactly once?

My attempt-

P(First to pic 2 balls)
                         $$6\cdot\frac{5}{6}\cdot5$$

P(next 2 balls(which  do not match the first 2 balls))-
                                $$4\cdot\frac 3 6 \cdot5  $$
P(next 2 balls(which do not match the balls at first and second pick))-
                                $$2\cdot\frac 1 6 \cdot5  $$

Therefore total probability=
$$\frac{6\cdot5\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1} {(6\cdot5)^3} =0.266$$

but my answer is wrong.
Can anybody help?

Comment: **Hint:** Let Peter picking two arbitrary balls

Answer (score 1):

Peter's choices are not relevant; he won't pick the same ball twice.

The chance that Paul's first ball is not among Peter's is 4/6; for the second ball, it's 3/5.

The chance that Mary's first ball is not among Peter's or Paul's is 2/6; for the second ball, it's 1/5.

So, your calculation $6\cdot5\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1/(6\cdot5)^3$ is right, but it's **0.0266**, not 0.266.